# listview only shows one item

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I want to add items to it from a foreach loop. My problem is that I can only see one item no matter how many I add. I've made an example code below with my problem in it. Starting with my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

      <TextView
          android:textSize="10pt"
          android:id="@+id/HeaderLbl"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

      <TextView
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:id="@+id/ErrorLbl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff0000"
            />
      <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/OrderSpinner"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               >
      </Spinner>

      <TextView
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:id="@+id/OrderRef"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

      <TextView
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:id="@+id/OrderDateTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

      <TextView
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:id="@+id/OrderCustomer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

      <TextView
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:id="@+id/OrderInnerComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

      <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/ArticleSpinner"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               >
      </Spinner>

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/OperationsListView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          >
      </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here I simulate my foreach loop adding items to it.

```
ArrayAdapter CalculationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
    ListView OperationsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.OperationsListView);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            CalculationAdapter.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        OperationsListView.Adapter = CalculationAdapter;
```

Help is most appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT:
I think the scrollview was the problem.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

I removed it and then it worked :)
Don't understand why tho..
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)
Mabye this can help any others with same prob

Comment: where did you set the adapter to the listview?

Comment: OperationsListView.Adapter = CalculationAdapter; right?

Answer (score 0):

use this to set adapter to the listview

```
 OperationsListView.setAdapter(CalculationAdapter);
```

This will set the values to the listview

and i am not sure whether `ListView OperationsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.OperationsListView);`

is right

try this

```
 OperationsListView = (ListView) findViewById(your id );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But when i posted my question two tags disappeared. Your answer is in java right? I'm working in monodroid with C#. In that case, sorry.

Comment: But you know what! I suspect the error is in the layout and it is the same right? You might be able to help me anyways if your pro with the layout

Comment: you might have the listitems in the list. (check them i think they will be visible when scrolled)

Comment: Can't scroll. But if that would be the problem, how do i remove the scrolling and make it a list showing all items?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `notifyDataSetChanged();` at the last.        `CalculationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: After OperationsListView.Adapter = CalculationAdapter; ?
Like this?
OperationsListView.Adapter = CalculationAdapter;
CalculationAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();